# Multiple errors trying to deploy project with wildfly 10

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, deployment, wildfly

I'm new to JSF and don't have an extensive experience with java on its own. Given a tutorial that provided the project files simply to download and import, I was supposed to deploy it using widlfly 10.
I haven't changed anything about the files.

I add the project to wildfly. Start the server, but the deployment is not successful. I don't know what else to tell since that's honestly all I did.

The log:

```
14:40:46,711 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.2.Final
14:40:46,920 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
14:40:46,990 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) starting
14:40:48,149 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0015: Re-attempting failed deployment rhdemo-service.war
14:40:48,187 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found rhdemo-service.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called rhdemo-service.war.dodeploy
14:40:48,208 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
14:40:48,222 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO version 3.4.0.Final
14:40:48,229 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.4.0.Final
14:40:48,286 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
14:40:48,290 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
14:40:48,299 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
14:40:48,306 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
14:40:48,316 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
14:40:48,346 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
14:40:48,346 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
14:40:48,344 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
14:40:48,345 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
14:40:48,420 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.3.4.Final)
14:40:48,425 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
14:40:48,505 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.6.Final
14:40:48,529 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.0.Final starting
14:40:48,535 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
14:40:48,546 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.21.Final
14:40:48,661 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
14:40:48,661 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
14:40:48,770 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\Jaguar651w\servers\jboss\wildfly-10.1.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
14:40:48,796 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
14:40:48,799 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
14:40:48,914 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
14:40:49,036 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYDM0111: Keystore C:\Jaguar651w\servers\jboss\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
14:40:49,042 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
14:40:49,060 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "rhdemo-service.war" (runtime-name: "rhdemo-service.war")
14:40:49,067 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Jaguar651w\servers\jboss\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments
14:40:49,265 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
14:40:49,308 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."rhdemo-service.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."rhdemo-service.war".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "rhdemo-service.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYUT0048: Failed to process WEB-INF/lib: "/C:/Jaguar651w/servers/jboss/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/rhdemo-service.war/WEB-INF/lib/jcompany-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.WarStructureDeploymentProcessor.deploy(WarStructureDeploymentProcessor.java:131)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYUT0048: Failed to process WEB-INF/lib: "/C:/Jaguar651w/servers/jboss/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/rhdemo-service.war/WEB-INF/lib/jcompany-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.WarStructureDeploymentProcessor.createResourceRoots(WarStructureDeploymentProcessor.java:233)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.WarStructureDeploymentProcessor.deploy(WarStructureDeploymentProcessor.java:126)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
    at org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem.<init>(JavaZipFileSystem.java:90)
    at org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem.<init>(JavaZipFileSystem.java:77)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.mountZip(VFS.java:386)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.mountZip(VFS.java:410)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.WarStructureDeploymentProcessor.createResourceRoots(WarStructureDeploymentProcessor.java:225)
    ... 7 more

14:40:49,327 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-3) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.4.Final
14:40:49,354 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
14:40:49,355 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
14:40:49,395 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
14:40:49,395 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
14:40:49,396 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
14:40:49,397 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
14:40:49,445 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.5.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.6) 
14:40:49,533 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "rhdemo-service.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"rhdemo-service.war\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"rhdemo-service.war\".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"rhdemo-service.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYUT0048: Failed to process WEB-INF/lib: \"/C:/Jaguar651w/servers/jboss/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/rhdemo-service.war/WEB-INF/lib/jcompany-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYUT0048: Failed to process WEB-INF/lib: \"/C:/Jaguar651w/servers/jboss/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/rhdemo-service.war/WEB-INF/lib/jcompany-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\"
    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"rhdemo-service.war\".STRUCTURE"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
14:40:49,571 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "rhdemo-service.war" (runtime-name : "rhdemo-service.war")
14:40:49,576 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."rhdemo-service.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."rhdemo-service.war".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "rhdemo-service.war"

14:40:49,672 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
14:40:49,673 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
14:40:49,673 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started (with errors) in 3269ms - Started 333 of 580 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 393 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
14:40:49,695 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment rhdemo-service.war (runtime-name: rhdemo-service.war) in 1ms
14:40:49,751 WARN  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0357: Notification of type deployment-undeployed is not described for the resource at the address []
14:40:49,752 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0009: Undeployed "rhdemo-service.war" (runtime-name: "rhdemo-service.war")
14:40:49,752 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."rhdemo-service.war".STRUCTURE

14:40:54,594 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found rhdemo-service.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called rhdemo-service.war.dodeploy
```

Thanks to anyone who can help

Comment: It looks like your `jcompany-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` is corrupt. You might need to rebuild it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today. Some jar was corrupted inside my maven local repository (~/.m2 in linux mint).
Deleted it, downloaded it again and rebuilt the project. Everything seems to be fine.